# View all GPU engine usage

Tags: monitoring, windows-10, task-manager, gpu

Task manager allows one to monitor upto 4 of the GPU engine's usage when *Change graph to > Multiple engines* option selected.

Is there any way to monitor all the available GPU engines?

It may not be possible in task manager itself, but is there any alternative tool that allows to monitor usage in all available engines (Should support nVidia and AMD GPUs as well)?

[image: Available GPU Engine options]

PS: I'm not sure whether this question should be asked in Software recommendation or Game development community. It seems better suited in Server fault community to me. Please feel free to move the topic to correct SE community if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need the 3rd party tool [Process Hacker](https://wj32.org/processhacker/nightly.php), open System properties (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, Go to `GPU` entry and click on `Nodes`

[image]

Comment: The file `kprocesshacker.sys` was detected as malware of type `Trojan.GenericKD.42094245` by BitDefender !

Comment: false positive. Use a different AV tool like NOD32

Comment: Can't change AV. It is company provided AV tool. I'll try to report to BitDefender so that it may unblock this assembly in their next update.

Comment: try to exclude the folder where you extracted the downloaded zip

Comment: Microsoft [started a "war" against Process Hacker](https://wj32.org/processhacker/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=11304#p11304). Looks like your AV suite blindly follows Microsoft and blocked this legit tools.

Comment: Yeah, MS sucks at many decisions on their products. Thanks!
Is there anyway to know what kind of tasks are those GPU nodes in ProcessHacker represents ? TaskManager shows `3D, Copy, Video Decode, Video Processing, GDI Render` etc. which helps one to analyze whats going on in GPU.

Comment: try run both tools same time and do an action (de-encode video, run a 3D Benchmark) and look which ProcessHacker graph has same usage like TaskManager. As written in the guide, Ms blocks some APIs, so PH can't display it

Comment: Microsoft stopped blocking ProcessHacker, so it should be also unblocked by other AV suites

Comment: @SenJacob On Windows 10 I also see the 3D, Copy so you can use ProcessHacker now. I will show you all data now.